# How to send a variable from react to node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm a beginner, and I'm trying to figure out how to send a variable generated from a function in react to the backend server side.

The user clicks on a button and a json object called rowObject is generated in home.jsx . I want to send it to backend to post.js to save it to the database. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your front end would make a request to your server, perhaps with something like [the browsers built in `fetch()` function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

For example:

```
function MyComponent() {
  function onClick() {
    fetch(
      '/some/path/here',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ myData: 123 })
      }
    )
  }

  return <div onClick={onClick}>Click Me</div>
}
```

Then on [the backend in express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) you would have something like:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.post('/some/path/here', (req, res) => {
  dbOrSomething.saveSomewhere(req.body) // your implementation here
  res.send('Saved!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```